# Jekyll - Invalid Date error after update

Tags: jekyll

I just updated jekyll to 1.3.0, everything was successful. But when I started the server with

```
    jekyll serve
```

I got the following error message:

```
    Generating...       Invalid Date: '' is not a valid datetime.
    Liquid Exception: exit in _posts/2010-10-23-mind-mapping-tony-buzan-5-minute-video.textile
```

Has something for the file name conventions? There is no date in the textile file. Before the update, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. It was a problem in my layout file where I used post.date instead of page.date .

Comment: But when I am using `{{ page.data | to_date_string }}`, it always throw this error. My jekyll version: 2.2.0.

Comment: @mytharcher page.date not page.data