# jekyll: Invalid Date: '' is not a valid datetime

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am new to jekyll:

So far I had done what the tutorial has mentioned: This is what I have in _layout: post.html file:

```
---
layout: default
---

<div class="post">
  <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
  <span class="post-date">{{ page.date | date_to_string }}</span>
  {{ content }}
</div>

<div class="related">
  <h2>Related Posts</h2>
  <ul class="related-posts">
    {% for post in site.related_posts limit:3 %}
      <li>
        <h3>
          <a href="{{ post.url }}">
            {{ post.title }}
            <small>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</small>
          </a>
        </h3>
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

and I use md file with a name `2014-01-01-myNewPost.md` and I get the following error:

```
      Generating...       Invalid Date: '' is not a valid datetime.
  Liquid Exception: exit in _layouts/post.html
```

I don't seem to see any issues but unable to really figure it out why its not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jekyll - Invalid Date error after update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936310/jekyll-invalid-date-error-after-update)

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that for some reason I kept getting this error in the terminal when I ran "jekyll serve --incremental":

```
Liquid Exception: Invalid Date: 'nil' is not a valid datetime. in /_layouts/post.html
         ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                ------------------------------------
                Invalid Date: 'nil' is not a valid datetime.
```

and after much digging, it's because jekyll picks up posts of any kind in the root directory, even if they are in a whole different folder. I had my posts in "_posts" and my test posts in "old_posts".

Just having the "old_posts" directory at the root project level made this error occur. Make sure you don't have anything like that.

Comment: Good answer. I had moved a bunch of dummy posts to another folder within project folder. Jekyll did not like it when I tried to rebuild the site.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you have moved the sample posts to another directory, e.g., `examples`. Jekyll finds the posts there and tries to process them, which leads to the encountered problem.

Add the `examples` folder to the exclude list in `_config.yml`, and Jekyll will start as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've a typo in the date variable in your post YAML matter. Check if your post date complies with this format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

I've checked the post layout code posted above, its fine.

If nothing works, uninstall Jekyll and install the last stable release 1.2.1 by running these commands

```
~ $ gem uninstall jekyll
~ $ gem install jekyll --version(="1.2.1")
```

Comment: If there is no date in the front matter, how can there be an error?

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen and it turns out I had duplicated a file from my _posts directory by mistake with option-click and it was sitting in the root of my site. Would be nice if the processor would give a detailed description about the cause of the error in addition to the general error message.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2003) it looks like Jekyll will complain if you label something as a post and then try to format the date if that thing doesn't have a date in the title or front matter. This doesn't happen if you reference `{{ page.date }}` without formatting it, so it must be some kind of nil error in the format function.

I just had this problem and I realized I'd labeled a bunch of static pages with `layout: post` in the front matter when the filename was `example.md` rather than `2016-01-01-example.md`. I changed those files to `layout: page` and that solved the problem.

So at least on my site I have to make sure things without dates are pages and things with dates are posts. (I removed the date from my posts layout when I redesigned the site and just now got around to trying to put it back.)